# Definition of (higher) derivatives of $f(x)$ at $x=a$ using the limits and $f$ itself.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

We know that if $f$ is differentiable at $x=a$, then

$$f'(a)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

---

Recently I knew that if $f$ is twice differentiable at $x=a$, then

$$f''(a)=\lim_{k \rightarrow 0} \bigg( \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+h+k)-f(a+h)-f(a+k)+f(a)}{hk} \bigg)$$

This can be re-expressed (with the indices of the limits being $h_1$ and $h_2$:

$$f''(a)=\lim_{h_2 \rightarrow 0} \bigg( \lim_{h_1 \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+h_1+h_2)-f(a+h_1)-f(a+h_2)+f(a)}{h_1h_2} \bigg)$$

---

I do not know how can we derive the above formula of $f''$, and how to derive higher order derivatives of a function which is $n$-times differentiable at $x=a$:

$$f^{(n)}(a)= \lim_{h_n \rightarrow 0} \big( \lim_{h_{n-1} \rightarrow 0} \big(\lim_{h_{n-2} \rightarrow 0} \big(\dots \big( \lim_{h_1 \rightarrow 0} \frac{\text{some expression involving }f \text{ only, with no derivatives}}{h_1h_2h_3\dots h_n} \big) \dots \big) \big) \big)$$

---

I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818942/writing-higher-order-derivatives-using-the-limit-definition-of-derivative), the answer is right but is not in the required form.

---

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Definition of the nth derivative? \[First post\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702185/definition-of-the-nth-derivative-first-post)

Comment: Doesn't the expression look pretty much like what you get if you write $\lim_{h_2\to 0} \frac{f'(a + h_2) - f'(a)}{h_2}$, expand $f'$, and then use limit laws?  For general $n$, what you'd get would probably look something like $\sum_{S \subseteq \{ 1, \ldots, n \}} (-1)^{n - |S|} f(a + \sum_{i\in S} h_i)$ in the numerator.